# Package "factoextra" non-zero exit status

Tags: r, cran, rstudio-server

I am attempting to install the package `factoextra` to work on cluster analysis, however I cannot get it to install properly. It is the package maintained by DataNovia, so I would assume the package should be functional and it is somehow on my end.

I am using RStudio server on a remote machine.

The error after attempting to install is :

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/abastuba/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘rio’
* removing ‘/home/abastuba/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rio’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rio’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rio’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/abastuba/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/car’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘rstatix’
* removing ‘/home/abastuba/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rstatix’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rstatix’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘FactoMineR’
* removing ‘/home/abastuba/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/FactoMineR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘FactoMineR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rstatix’ is not available for package ‘ggpubr’
* removing ‘/home/abastuba/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/ggpubr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggpubr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘FactoMineR’, ‘ggpubr’ are not available for package ‘factoextra’
* removing ‘/home/abastuba/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/factoextra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘factoextra’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPkt3bC/downloaded_packages’
```

I am not sure how to fix this and this package would be extremely useful for my project, if anyone has experience figuring out how to get the package to install it would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to load the package with `library(factoextra)` however it appears it truely isn't installed as I get thrown an error that there is no such package.

Comment: try adding `dependencies = T` in the install command

Comment: Did you see the message in the "ANTICONF ERROR" section? Your system is missing a dependency. Use the command given in that message that corresponds to your particular operating system.